# Unable to handle body data along with image file in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I want to send image file along with various data.
The issue is when i send file using formdata/multipart the body data comes in string. So my dto is giving error. [image]
Is there any way to parse cetain fields to number/array before it reaches the dto??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens only with postman, in Postman formmultipart everthing is sent as text. Wont happen when you use Axios in front end